# Providing multiple localization files under one JSF variable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, localization, internationalization

Is it possible to provide multiple localization files under one JSF variable?

I would like split localization messages to many files to make working on the easier (SVN conflicts etc.). Additionally I would like to exclude the common part and put it in the module shared between various projects. But I would like to access everything under one `i18n` name, first to avoid changes in existing JSF files, second to hide from developerst the technical details how the localization files are splitted and allow more flexibility in organizing such files.

My configuration:

- PrimeFaces 3.4
- Myfaces 2.0.7

Comment: Are you possible using Spring framework in you project?

Comment: Yes, so spring-based colution could be interesting.

Comment: Yes, with spring it is easy. I will show in answer my solution. You can add Spring tag, as it will help.

Comment: In fact, I already found almost the same solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12899904/759126)

Comment: My understanding is, you need to provide your own class to read from resources. Yes, it is possible with standard API, but no one gave you any answer... I am no sure if you still need it, though.