# jsf2 loading a resource bundle defined defined in a JAR

Tags: jsf, resourcebundle

I'm creating a modular JSF 2.0 application and each of the modules has their own faces-config and the facelet pages. These modules are packaged into JAR and consumed in a master JSF2 application. Everything works fine but the resource bundles defined in each of the faces-config files are not resolved at the runtime. Not resolved means the respective text is not displayed in the pages. I refer to the message as `<h:outputText value="#{msg['message1']}" />`

how do I make it work?

Comment: No one who has an answer for this?

Answer (score 5):

After some research it seems, resource-bundles defined in faces-config files in a JAR file are not resolved at run time. The only solution is to use `<f:loadBundle var="msg" basename="messages"/>` explicitly in the facelet page. Then it will resolve the messages.properties inside the JAR file.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my afternoon ;-) I confirm this works with JSF 2.2.13

Answer (score 2):

This is an old topic but maybe could help someone.

Another possible solution is to declare two different bundles in faces-config.xml. Something like that:

```
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>msgsprj</base-name>
        <var>msgsPrj</var>
    </resource-bundle>

    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>msgsfmk</base-name>
        <var>msgsFmk</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

So in your XHTML's you can use them this way:

```
#{msgsFmk['generic.msg.remove']}
```

As well it would be good idea to take a look at this topic:

[Using Multiple Resource bundles in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786618/using-multiple-resource-bundles-in-jsf)

Answer (score 0):

When packed as `jar`, `faces-config.xml` must be at `/classes/META-INF/` dir, and it is not necessary to add the `f:loadBundle` in each `facelet`